# IdeaPad S340 Ryzen & ubuntu

Tags: laptop, lenovo, amd-ryzen

Did somebody try to install Ubuntu on Ryzen variant of Lenovo IdeaPad S340?
I would like to try Lenovo IdeaPad S340-15API (81NC004VCK) but I worry that it will be useless on Linux.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS derivative Linux Mint 19.1 is supposed to install on the L 340. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=295978 I don't know but think the L series is for laptops with the Intel CPU and S series for those with the Ryzen CPU. Don't know what other differences might be.

Comment: "Duplicate"? Why? It is different HW. Compatibility is not problem of used CPU only.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I am try to test it.
It looks, that it works fine.

- Ubuntu 18.04LTS need update kernel (I am using 5.0.0, it is needed for graphic accelerator).
- Ubuntu 19.10 works "out of the box".
- MINT 19.2 is same as Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Here is ouput from "inxi -Fxzd" command:

```
System:    Host: xxxxxxxx Kernel: 5.0.0-32-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.4.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.2.4 
           Distro: Linux Mint 19.2 Tina base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 81NC v: Lenovo IdeaPad S340-15API serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0J40700 WIN serial: <filter> UEFI: LENOVO v: AMCN25WW(V1.08) date: 07/25/2019 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 52.3 Wh condition: 52.5/52.5 Wh (100%) model: LENOVO PABAS0241231 status: Unknown 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen rev: 1 
           L2 cache: 2048 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 33536 
           Speed: 1222 MHz min/max: 1400/2100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1248 2: 1274 3: 1272 4: 1252 5: 1223 6: 1222 7: 1397 
           8: 1397 
Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Picasso vendor: Lenovo driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 04:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: amdgpu,ati unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.27.0 5.0.0-32-generic LLVM 8.0.0) v: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.8 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 04:00.1 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A bus ID: 04:00.5 
           Device-3: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 04:00.6 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.0.0-32-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Lenovo driver: ath10k_pci v: kernel 
           bus ID: 02:00.0 
           IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Atheros type: USB driver: btusb bus ID: 3-2:2
```

Works: Accelerated graphic in full resolution, keyboard, touchpad, USB ports, sound, headphones jack, camera, WiFi, NVMe disk, SDcard slot

Not tested: HDMI, battery life

Answer (score 0):

Laptop need 11~12 Watt in idle (7W with minimal backlight)

Output from cpupower idle-info

```
CPUidle driver: acpi_idle
CPUidle governor: menu
analyzing CPU 0:

Number of idle states: 3
Available idle states: POLL C1 C2
POLL:
Flags/Description: CPUIDLE CORE POLL IDLE
Latency: 0
Usage: 12972
Duration: 41718
C1:
Flags/Description: ACPI FFH MWAIT 0x0
Latency: 1
Usage: 1043996
Duration: 425342576
C2:
Flags/Description: ACPI IOPORT 0x414
Latency: 400
Usage: 1305684
Duration: 3956360158
```